# Select all values of an attribute and return as list using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have a XML document with multiple recursive attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d2LogicalModel xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" modelBaseVersion="2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <publicationTime>2020-04-21T12:31:11.651Z</publicationTime>
        <situation id="1234" version="5">
            <someRecord>value</someRecord>
            <situationRecord xsi:type="Type1" id="type1_id_001" version="01">
                <situationRecordCreationTime>2020-03-16T14:59:30Z</situationRecordCreationTime>
            </situationRecord>
            <situationRecord xsi:type="Type1" id="type1_id_002" version="01">
                <situationRecordCreationTime>2020-03-16T14:59:30Z</situationRecordCreationTime>
            </situationRecord>
            <situationRecord xsi:type="Type2" id="type2_id_001" version="01">
                <situationRecordCreationTime>2020-03-16T14:59:30Z</situationRecordCreationTime>
                <attributes>
                    <att>attribute1</att>
                    <att>attribute2</att>
                    <att>attribute3</att>
                    <attUsage>attribute1Usage</attUsage>
                </attributes>
            </situationRecord>
        </situation>
</d2LogicalModel>
```

So there can be 1 or more `situation` element, each containing one or more `situationRecord` elements.
I want to extract some of the attributes and transform it into a Python dictionary. I Therefore use the following XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:pub="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!--predefined separator for further use-->
        <xsl:variable name="sep" select="','"/>
        <!--set column names-->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('situation_id', $sep,
                              'situation_version', $sep,
                            'situation_record_id', $sep,
                       'situation_record_version', $sep,
                          'situation_record_type', $sep,
                 'situation_record_creation_time', $sep,
                                     'attributes', '&#xa;')"/>

        <!--predefined separator for further use-->
        <xsl:for-each select="//pub:situation">
            <!--get ids for each further record-->
            <xsl:variable name="ref.id" select="@id"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ref.version" select="@version"/>

            <xsl:for-each select="pub:situationRecord">
                <!--get all required values in variables for further result concat-->
                <xsl:variable name="pub.time" select="ancestor::pub:payloadPublication/pub:publicationTime"/>
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
                <xsl:variable name="version" select="@version"/>
                <xsl:variable name="type" select="@xsi:type"/>
                <xsl:variable name="situationRecordCreationTime" select="pub:situationRecordCreationTime"/>
                <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="concat(pub:attributes/pub:att,'-')"/>

                <!--getting result with concat function-->
                <xsl:value-of select="concat($ref.id, $sep,
                                        $ref.version, $sep,
                                                 $id, $sep,
                                            $version, $sep,
                                               $type, $sep,
                        $situationRecordCreationTime, $sep,
                                         $attributes, '&#xa;')"/>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works fine for all elements except for the `attributes` element. I would like to select all of the `att` element values and return it as a comma separated list or string.

Desired output: `attribute1,attribute2,attribute3`

I can get all values from the `attributes` element as a string using:

```
<xsl:variable name="attributes" select="pub:attributes"/>
```

Which returns `attribute1attribute2attribute3attribute1Usage`. This also returns the attUsage value, which should not be the case.

Or use:

```
<xsl:variable name="attributes" select="concat(pub:attributes/pub:att,'-')"/>
```

Which only returns `attribute1-`

How can I solve this using XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate through the elements and output them with the separator you want:

You can replace this line in your transformation :

```
<xsl:variable name="attributes" select="concat(pub:attributes/pub:att,'-')"/>
```

By this :

```
            <xsl:variable name="attributes">
                <xsl:for-each select="pub:attributes/pub:att">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                  <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'-'"/>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I implement this in my current XSL structure? I need the output in a xsl:variable name I believe in order to use it in my column names.